# How do I fail the booking if the booked boolean field is set to True in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am having trouble making if/else work in my django app, I want to check if a listing is booked, booked is a boolean field and the listing is a foreign key to the Booking class where the user selects a listing to book. Now I just want to know how that foreign key can be checked if the listing is booked so it fails to book and gives an error.

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        tickets = models.Booking.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
        return render(request, "profile.html", {'form': forms.BookingForm(), 'tickets': tickets})

    else:
        try:
            form = forms.BookingForm(request.POST)
            new_ticket = form.save(commit=False)

            new_ticket.user = request.user
            new_ticket.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Booking Created Successfully')
            return redirect('profile')

        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': forms.BookingForm()})
```

models.py

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=755)
    price = MoneyField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    booked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # avail_days = models.ForeignKey(Days, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # how to check if listing is booked and deny if it is True ?
    # day = models.OneToOneField(Days, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_booked = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: You can add function to `Listing` model.

`@property
def is_booked(self):
    return self.booking_set.all().exists()`

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you edit my code if possible? how would it look in views and models?

Comment: To be sure. If user already booked `Listing` object, you want to prevent to book it again, is that your purpose?

Comment: purpose is that if the listing is set to booked=True then any user should not be able to book, he gets error message

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `booked` field in `Listing` model, you can do this (you can also render `Listing` objects with `booked=False`):

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        tickets = models.Booking.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
        return render(request, "profile.html", {'form': forms.BookingForm(), 'tickets': tickets})

    else:
        try:
            form = forms.BookingForm(request.POST)
            new_ticket = form.save(commit=False)

            # here you can do something like
            if new_ticket.listing.booked:
                messages.error(request, 'Booked Already')
                return redirect('profile')

            new_ticket.user = request.user
            new_ticket.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Booking Created Successfully')
            return redirect('profile')

        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': forms.BookingForm()})
```

models.py

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=755)
    price = MoneyField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    booked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # avail_days = models.ForeignKey(Days, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # how to check if listing is booked and deny if it is True ?
    # day = models.OneToOneField(Days, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_booked = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.listing.booked = True
        self.listing.save()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```